# How do I download coffee_bot.py file for coffee challenge tutorial?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://learn.turtlebot.com/2015/02/01/22/ here you mentioned that we need to make changes to coffee_bot.py file.
How do I download this file?

-Sakshi

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265069/how-do-i-download-coffee_bot.py-file-for-coffee-challenge-tutorial?/) by [Sakshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/30949/sakshi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2017-06-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The file can be found and downloaded from here:

https://github.com/markwsilliman/turtlebot

or alternatively by running this command:

`git clone https://github.com/markwsilliman/turtlebot/`

---

Originally posted by [procyon](https://answers.ros.org/users/30951/procyon/) with karma: 26 on 2017-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sakshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/30949/sakshi/) on 2017-06-30**:
thanks for the response. I got the files.
Also I wanted to ask where can I find the coffeebot.launch file?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-15**:
@Sakshi, if this answered your question you should mark it as correct.